# Circumvent super call of inherited class with wrong type declaration

Tags: typescript

I am using an external library that ships with type definitions. Unfortunately, one exported class adds that some methods by using mixins that are not present in the type definitions.
When I now call `super`, like

```js
import { ExternalClass } from "foobar"

class MyClass extends ExternalClass {
  public foobar() {
    super.foobar()
  }
}
```

I get the error `Property 'foobar' does not exist on type 'ExternalClass'`. Is there any way around it and without re-declaring the whole `ExternalClass` (it's huge)? I tried things like `(super as any).foobar()`, but found no way to calm the Typescript gods.

Here is a little [real-world example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-wvirj?file=/index.ts).

Answer (score 1):

While the library you are using has not complete definition files, you can take advantage of type [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add the definitions of the functions you need to call:

```
import { ExternalClass } from "foobar";

declare module "foobar" {
  interface ExternalClass {
    foobar(): void;
  }
}

class MyClass extends ExternalClass {
  public foobar() {
    super.foobar() // OK
  }
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsBMFNQJ6QK6mpAdgcgC6kgO4YBQxAxgDYCGAzjaAKIAeOsAThlReNXaAN7FQoEIwC2ABxwJ8GUBORsJkGrGIBfUqKhxEKfEVIBLDKzYAzKmXjMznbr3qDhw85EgAjKmwAUASgAuUAA3SCNoAG4NUkpaegBZBB440FgWWAxoelt2e2S%20Z3lkDwojMlA3T29-ASEXGmQJdgA6Sq9fPxEwAHkAaTrNdSA)

As more straightforward solution, you can also use [`// @ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#example-3) to suppress all the errors originating from your line of code.

Comment: I am importing the module with ESM syntax (updated the example in the question) and unfortunately, when trying the declaration merging I get the following error on the import statement `Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'ExternalClass'.` Does this not work for imported classes?!

Comment: Yes it works but you have to declare it in a `module`, I've adapted my answer

Comment: Well, this is another point. Just `import { ExternalClass as Foo } from "foobar";`

Comment: @Guerric P: Unfortunately, I then end up with `Cannot extend an interface 'CstParser'. Did you mean 'implements'?`. Here is a little real-world example: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-wvirj?file=/index.ts

Comment: Indeed, not sure why it doesn't work in the context of a module

Comment: @GuerricP Nevertheless, thanks for the help. Using `// @ts-ignore` for now and opened an issue on the external repo to add the type def. I vote your answer up, but leave the question open for a more elegant solution (I really liked the idea of declaration merging).

Comment: Yeah I like it too that's why I tried to provide an answer based on this, unsuccesfully  thanks for the vote though!